# Powershell invoke-command not returning value of get-itemproperty

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-remoting

I'm writing a script to retrieve the pool recycling parameters from IIS Servers.

My problem is that locally the command works fine (I get the correct result in minutes) :

```
(Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\MyPool" -Name "Recycling.Periodicrestart.Time.Value").totalminutes
```

But when launching remotely with `invoke-command`, nothing comes back, The `$RecycleTimeInterval` value is `$null`:

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName MyServer
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration}
$PoolArray = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\AppPools' -Verbose}
ForEach($pool in $PoolArray) {
    $PoolName = $pool.Name
    $RecycleTimeInterval = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {(Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\$args[0] -Name 'Recycling.Periodicrestart.Time.Value').totalminutes} -ArgumentList $PoolName
    }
}
```

Note that the `Get-ChildItem` command to get the pool list works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the value with :

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName MyServer
Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration}
$PoolArray = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path 'IIS:\AppPools' -Verbose}
ForEach($pool in $PoolArray) {
    $PoolName = $pool.Name
    $RecycleTimeInterval = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
        param($SBPoolName)
        (Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\$SBPoolName).Recycling.Periodicrestart.Time.TotalMinutes}
        -ArgumentList $PoolName
    }
}
```